# Selecting Best features for ML

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Is there any way to extract best features from the data. Right now, I am using 'KBest' from sklearn.
In this, I have to specify number of K best features that needs to be selected.
Is there any way in which I don't have to specify the number of features to be extracted? Rather we extract all the useful features?

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
test = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"all"` instead of a number

```
test = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k="all")
```

From [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html)

> k : int or “all”, optional, default=10
>
> Number of top features to select. The “all” option bypasses selection, for use in a parameter
> search.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to select features. In [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection), you can find them.And I think the best feature selection method is that you have a deep understanding of these features.But usually we have a hard time understanding them.

Maybe you can use 5-Kfold cross-validation to make a feature importance ranking, and them select important feature from it.

And you also can use `Embedded` method to select it, like this:

```py
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

#Feature selection of GBDT as base model
SelectFromModel(GradientBoostingClassifier()).fit_transform(iris.data, iris.target)
```

It's worth noting that you cannot delete a feature that seems to be useless alone,because it may be related to other features.So feature selection is a greedy search process, which is often time consuming.